# How to upgrade opengl to 3.3 in vmware

Tags: opengl, vmware, x11, glx

Here is my glxinfo showing:

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.1, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.1.7
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 20.1.7
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 20.1.7
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

And I want to upgrade opengl version to 3.3, I assume this will also upgrade the glsl and opengles? How could I do this?

Comment: Looks like you already have 3.3, just gotta make Core contexts.

Comment: Or dump time/money into Mesa to enable 3.2+ on Compatibility contexts.

Comment: @genpfault emmm, I'm not sure how to do this... Could you be more specific? I thought it should show 3.3 in "OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 20.1.7" here?

Comment: Via [`glXCreateContextAttribsARB()`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.0_Context_Creation_\(GLX\))